# Aplicação Node.js cai sempre após um erro

Tags: node.js, recuperação-de-erros

Tenho uma aplicação em Node.js que sempre que ocorre algum erro ela cai, tendo que ser restartada manualmente, sempre. Como faço para que o erro seja reportado, mas a aplicação continue rodando?

Comment: Qual o erro exibido? Provavelmente é mais válido tentar consertar o erro do que restartar o NodeJS. Poste mais detalhes. Em todo caso, para restartar o NodeJS, seria necessário um job verificando de tempos em tempos se sua aplicação esta executando, e caso não esteja, execute-a novamente.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Vinícius. Resolvi como você falou, consertei a função que estava dando o erro. Foi só

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Vinícius. Resolvi como você falou, consertei a função que estava dando o erro. Foi só colocar um callback que tava no lugar errado. Vlw

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar que sua aplicação crashe com erros você também pode usar os métodos try() e catch(), exemplo:

```js
var exemploFunc = function(req, res) {
    try {
      console.log('Nenhum erro :)');
    } catch(e) {
      console.log('Ops, um erro ocorreu!');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade para capturar exceções num nível global é usar

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```

mas é considerado uma prática ruim, porque o seu programa pode ficar num estado inconsistente depois da exceção. É um remendo para emergências!

O ideal é testar bem seu programa para reduzir ao máximo as exceções devidas a bugs, e manter ele rodando usando um script que recarrega o node assim que ele sair. Exceções que não são bugs devem ser capturadas "perto" de onde acontecem, não num nível global.

Answer (score 0):

Passa parametro **reconnect** recebendo **true** quando estiver abrindo a conexão.

```
io.connect(                                                                 // CRIAR UM SOCKET
            $("#socket").val(),{                                            // ENDERECO DO SOCKET
            'reconnect': true                                               // que irá informar se o socket irá tentar se conectar caso perca a conexão com o Server.
           ,'reconnection delay': 500                                       // informa o tempo em milissegundos que será o delay da tentativa de conexão.
           ,'max reconnection attempts': 1000                               // informa o valor máximo de tentativas de conexão com o Server.
           ,'secure': false                                                 // informando se a conexão com o Server irá utilizar criptografia (conexões HTTPS).
    });
```

Vou passar um exemplo mais completo abaixo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo utilizando socket.io</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">
        h2 { 
            color: #439;
            font-size: 120%;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8088/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Criando a conexão com o Socket.io
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8088',{
             'reconnect': true
            ,'reconnection delay': 500
            ,'max reconnection attempts': 1000
            ,'secure': false
        });

        // Emitindo o evento para o Server
        socket.emit('userconected');

        // Listeners

        /**
         * Monitorando o evento "showmessage" que será disparado pelo Server
         * @param {String} msg Mensagem a ser exibida
         */
        socket.on('showmessage', function(msg){
            var messageEl = document.getElementById('message-info');

            // Exibindo a mensagem enviada
            messageEl.innerHTML += msg;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Mensagens do socket.io</h2>
    <div id="message-info"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Código exemplo do site: http://wessdevel.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/instalando-e-configurando-nodejs-e.html